# Sans serif appendix page

Tags: appendices, sans-serif, scrbook

I'm using the scrbook class and `\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}` for my appendices.

The inserted appendixpage appears to be typeset in rmfamily. How can i change it to sans-serif?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\chapter{some chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{some appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, with `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{%
\normalfont}{%
\sffamily}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{some chapter}

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{some appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]